# Why is implementing a while statement in viewDidLoad not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8, viewdidload

I am trying to have a while statement in the `viewDidLoad` section, but it does not seem to be working. Maybe someone could take a shot at it? Here is the `while` statement:

```
    NSString *t1activity = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                      stringForKey:@"t1"];

while ([t1activity isEqualToString:@"active"]) {
    NSString *t1Active = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          stringForKey:@"t1"];
    if ([t1Active isEqualToString:@"active"]) {

        NSString *t1Subject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               stringForKey:@"t1Subject"];
        NSString *t1Unit = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"t1Unit"];
        NSString *t1Minutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               stringForKey:@"t1Minutes"];
        NSString *t1StudyTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                 stringForKey:@"t1StudyTime"];
        // NSDate *t1TestDay = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        //                             objectForKey: @"t1TestDay"];

        _SubjectValue.text = t1Subject;
        _UnitValue.text = t1Unit;
        _MinutesValue.text = t1Minutes;
        _StudyTimeValue.text = t1StudyTime;
        // _TestDayValue.text = t1TestDay;

        NSString *t1Mute= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           stringForKey:@"t1Mute"];

        if ([t1Mute isEqualToString:@"unmute"]) {

            NSString *valueToSave = @"mute";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"t1Mute"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


            [_muteButton setTitle:@"Unmute test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else {

            NSString *valueToSave = @"unmute";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"t1Mute"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


            [_muteButton setTitle:@"Mute test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }      
}
}
```

I don't know what's going on. I'm just trying to make this statement run the whole time the view is displayed. The goal is to refresh the users data they can easily edit. If this wont work, can someone help me find another way to try what I described? Thank you!

Comment: You can't just loop around inside `viewDidLoad`  - this will block your programs execution.  You need to write event-driven code.  Perhaps explain in more detail what you are trying to do; How are the default settings supposed to change? By the user using controls on screen?  Also, you don't need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: Im trying to load data when the user either removes the value - or edits it. So I want it to run like the whole time. Also why no synchronize?

Comment: You need to update things *when* the user changes them, you can't observe changes in a loop like this, since this will prevent the rest of your code from running.  You can use `NSNotification`s if you want to decouple, or simply update the UI directly when the user changes the control.  You don't need synchronize as UserDefaults automatically updates the disk store; refer to the documentation